# Integration of GHS MULTI with Rational Team Concert

Tags: rtc, greenhills

I am planning to use IBM RTC for configuration management, for work in GHS MULTI environment. WE are moving to RTC from ClearCase. Is there a ready solution for such integration? Do we need some additional tools for it?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any native integration available between RTC and GHS.
The only trace I can find is in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/95236/subject-jazz-source-conrol-integration-with-greenhills-multi-ide):

> What SCM interface does that tool support?
>   With 4.x on windows you could try **[MSSCC](https://jazz.net/library/article/1107)** or the shell (if it does not support MSSCC or integrate in Eclipse or Visual Studio). You could try to use the SCM command line to create an interface if that tool supports that.

From [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/91726/visual-source-safe-api-available-with-rtc-software):

> MSSCC is defined by Microsoft. Any consumers of MSCC have to conform to that interface.
>   Jazz MSCCI implements the server side of the interface.
>   The idea is that tools that support this interface, can use it and work against Jazz SCM.
>   Since the interface is very ancient (I remember it being around 1995) it is widely supported by tools

(documentation: [wiki articles](https://jazz.net/search_results.jsp?q=MSScci#page=0&type=type=Document-WikiPage&q=MSScci), [forums](https://jazz.net/search_results.jsp?q=MSScci#page=0&type=type=Document-ForumThread&q=MSScci): you need a jazz.net account to see the results)